# How do I override an generic method?(C#)

Tags: c#, .net, collections

I'm creating a class named `TetraQueue` that inherits `System.Collections.Generic.Queue` class overriding the `Dequeue` method, here is the code:

```
public class TetraQueue : Queue<Tetrablock>
{
   public override Tetrablock Dequeue()
   {
       return base.Dequeue();
   }
 }
```

But when I try to compile this I get:

> Error TetraQueue.Dequeue()': no suitable method found to override  TetraQueue.cs

Thanks in advance.

How do I know if a method is virtual(to avoid this kind of situation)?

Comment: I assume you meant "Dequeue" rather than "Dequeque"? You wouldn't be able to override that way even if Dequeue were virtual :) I'll let you edit the question though, in case I'm wrong.

Comment: Just to point out if that's all you wanted your overrided method to do was return base.Dequeue() it will do that by default without needing to attempt to override it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately the `Dequeue` method is not virtual so you can't override it.

Answer (score 9):

Two ways to know whether or not a method is virtual:

- Type in "override" in Visual Studio - it will offer you all the methods you're allowed to override.
- [View the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1c8bzx97.aspx) - Dequeue doesn't say it's virtual, so you can't override it.

EDIT: Others have suggested hiding the method. I strongly recommend that you *don't* do that unless you really, really have to. It's a recipe for difficult debugging sessions and frustration when inheritance *appears* to sometimes work and sometimes not, depending on the compile-time type of the reference. Blurgh. If you're not going to specialize the behaviour, use composition instead of inheritance.

Comment: Composition is a highly-underrated technique. I always try to think very carefully whether inheritance or composition is needed.

Answer (score 5):

you have to use the **new** keyword.  This will tell the compiler that you want this method put on top of the other one.  Just a warning though, if you are using the base class such as Queue you will not be able to use this new method.

```
public class TetraQueque : Queue<Tetrablock>
{
   public new Tetrablock Dequeque()
   {
       return base.Dequeue();
   }
}
```

Comment: This is method hiding, NOT overriding. Big difference.

Answer (score 1):

Add the new keyword to hide the method on the base class.

A good article on the polymorphism in .net: http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_polymorphism.html

Answer (score 1):

Queue has no Deque**q**ue method but a Dequeue method. That would be the first compile error, if you fix that, you still can't compile because it's not a virtual method.

Using the new keyword you could reintroduce this method, but remember to spell the function name correct, or there will be a `.Dequeue` and a `.Dequeque` method.

The question itself also contains this spelling error.

Answer (score 1):

It is pointless to override a method to only call the parent, so if the code you posted is all you're doing, then don't override it.

By making your TetraQueue a Queue<TetraBlock> you're saying it can be used whenever a Queue<TetraBlock> can be. By adding a new method to it which hides the original method if the caller knows its TetraQueue, then you're messing with that contract.

If I wanted the same behaviour as Queue I'd use a Queue<TetraBlock>; if I wanted something different I'd use composition rather than inheritance.

Comment: I think this explanation could easily have two or three times as much detail, but this is certainly the core of the matter.

Answer (score 1):

As has been previously mentioned, you cannot override the method because it is non-virtual. However, I would strongly urge you not to hide the method.  Consider the following:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            A a = new A();
            B b = new B();
            A c = new B();

            // Straight A
            a.MyVirtualMethod();
            a.MyNonVirtualMethod();

            // Straight B
            b.MyVirtualMethod();
            b.MyNonVirtualMethod();

            // Polymorphic
            c.MyVirtualMethod();
            c.MyNonVirtualMethod();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class A
    {
        public virtual void MyVirtualMethod()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello world!");
        }

        public void MyNonVirtualMethod()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello world!");
        }
    }

    public class B : A
    {
        public override void MyVirtualMethod()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Good bye universe!");
        }

        public new void MyNonVirtualMethod()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Good bye universe!");
        }
    }
```

The output of this code is not obvious to somebody that doesn't understand the implementation.

```
Hello world!
Hello world!
Good bye universe!
Good bye universe!
Good bye universe!
Hello world!
```